# I want to start developing Dart Applications using Eclipse IDE, but when I add the Dart SDK on Eclipse, its saying: Not a valid SDK location

Tags: eclipse, plugins, dart

I want to develop Dart Applications using Eclipse IDE. So the process is that you have to install the Dart Plugin for eclipse and I have done that.

Then I have to configure the Dart SDK through point Eclipse to the Dart SDK Location and I have done that, by going to Window, Preferences, Dart - Then browse to Dart SDK Location as: C:\dart-sdk, but Eclipse is saying: Not a valid Dart SDK location.

So because of that the Apply button remains grayed and I cant apply. So please help.

Comment: Please add screenshots of what you are doing. You need to install the Dart SDK using the Preferences page.

Comment: Possibly related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48650831/dart-sdk-is-not-configured looks like you need a relative path under `../bin/cache/dart-sdk` rather than a random folder, probably due to libraries it depends on.

Comment: @harrymc and Spikey_richie, please see note that i am doing that under Eclipse Preferences and the directory i have pointed it to is : C:\dart-sdk and it failed and it failed and then tried: C:\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk but it still says: Not a valid SDK location

Comment: Maybe the message is correct and the SDK is wrong or wrongly installed?

Comment: @harrymc - i just left the eclipse as it is with the message the message that: Its not a valid SDK and proceeded to try and create a new dart project that i named helloworld and surprising its working and am getting results after doing RUN FILE. Below is the code: main(){
 int a=3, b=5;
 int sum=a+b;
 print("$a"'+'"$b= $sum");
 String name="Obert";
 print("Name is: $name");
}

Comment: This corresponds better with my (general) knowledge, so I added an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Installing the Dart Plugin for Eclipse is supposed to install everything that is
required for Dart projects.

There is no need to install separately the SDK.

Comment: Hi, i dont think so, because for IntelliJ IDEA, you have to install the Dart Plugin and then configure IntelliJ IDEA to point to a location where the Dart SDK is located. This is the correct process. And its the same for Eclipse.

Comment: Do you have another explanation as to why Dart works?